# How can I get a range's hyperlink in Google Spreadsheets API?

Tags: python, api, google-sheets, hyperlink

How can I get a hyperlink for the range B3:B and print on the terminal

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()

result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId="SPREADSHEET_ID",range="Sheet1!B3:B").execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
print(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the spreadsheet ID, the sheet ID (`gid`) and A1 notation of the range. Then use normal string manipulation to build the link. The end result should look like this:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/2t2g9WZsvjP1hqdBte9Cozo0Qrt7PofqSaovMNzES12Q/edit#gid=113010599&range=B3:B`